# Sort a list from different classes by one field - Django

Tags: python, django, django-queryset

I connect multiple queryset from different objects into one list:

```
query_1 = Room.objects.all()
query_2 = Apartment.objects.all()
query_3 = Plot.objects.all()

all_user_objects = list(chain(query_1, query_2, query_3))
```

How can I add a sort by `created_at` date from the newest?

I try this:

```
all_user_objects.order_by('-created_at')
```

and this:

```
from operator import attrgetter
all_user_objects = list(chain(query_1, query_2, query_3), key=attrgetter('-created_at'))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [sorted()](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/sorting.html) for this:

```
from operator import attrgetter

all_user_objects = list(sorted(chain(query_1, query_2, query_3), key=attrgetter('created_at'), reverse=True))
```